# aligning chart and tablix in parallell

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have two chart and tablix in my SSRS report. Degin page looks as follows

[image: Design page]

The second chart in the report is shown after the tablix data. I need to show the data in parallel. The second chart should be available immediately following the first chart.

[image: Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the table in a rectangle then simply put it under the bar chart. Make sure there are no overlaps on the objects.